# How to display 1 sorting comparison every 1 second in php?

Tags: php, sorting, sleep, bubble-sort

I want to display every 1 second only 1 comparison in order to see visually how the the array is being sorted step by step .

I tried to add sleep(1) in the end of the nested loop and the page keeps loading without displaying anything

```
<?php

$my_array = [100,99,98,97,96];

function bubblesort($my_array){

    $comparisons = 0;
$len = count($my_array);


    for( $i = 0 ; $i < $len ; $i++){
        for( $j = 0 , $temp = 0 ; $j < $len - 1 ; $j++ ){

            $comparisons++;
      

            if ($my_array[$j] > $my_array[$j+1] ){

                $temp = $my_array[$j+1];
                $my_array[$j+1] = $my_array[$j];
                $my_array[$j] = $temp;
                

                

            } // end of if conditional

        } // end of inner for loop
      } // end of first for loop
      echo '<h4>' . $comparisons . ' Comparisons</h4>';
      return $my_array;
    } // end of bubbleSort()
    
    
    echo '<strong>Before Sorting</strong><br>' . implode( ', ', $my_array ) . '<br>';
    $sorted = bubbleSort( $my_array );
    echo '<strong>After Sorting</strong><br>' . implode( ', ', $sorted );



?>
```

any ideas ?

Comment: due to the nature of client server, you simply can't send multiple response for the same request. The easy way is switching to cli. The hard way is using ajax and multiple request for each step you want to track

Comment: Agreed, however, please note that an ajax approach would likely create issues with a delay of only 1 second because ajax requests are asynchronous and not guaranteed to return in the same order they were sent and 1 second is just too short to be reliable

Comment: You might find it easier to send all the results at once and use a client side timer to display one result per second.